# Odd dropping of pandas rows based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use the function:

```
def df_proc(df, n):
    print (list(df.lab).count(0)) # control label to see if it changes after conditional dropping
    print ('C:', list(df.lab).count(1))

    df = df.drop(df[df.lab.eq(0)].sample(n).index)

    print (list(df.lab).count(0))
    print ('C:', list(df.lab).count(1))

    return df
```

To drop pandas rows based on certain conditions (where df.lab == 0). This works fine on a small df (e.g. n = 100) however when I increase the number of rows in the df something odd happens ... the counts of other labels (!= 0) also begin to decrease and are affected by the condition..

For example:

```
# dummy example:
import random
list2 = [random.randrange(0, 6, 1) for i in range(1500000)] 
list1 = [random.randrange(0, 100, 1) for i in range(1500000)] 
dft = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list1, list2)), columns = ['A', 'lab'])
dftest = df_proc(dft,100000)
```

gives...

```
249797
C: 249585
149797
C: 249585
```

But when I run this on my actual df:

```
dftest = df_proc(S1,100000)
```

I get a change in my control labels which is weird.

```
467110
C: 70434
260616
C: 49395
```

I'm not sure where the error could have come from. I have tried using `frac` and `df.query('lab == 0')` but still run into the same error. The other thing I noticed is that with small `n` the control labels are unchanged, its only when I increase `n`.

```
dftest = df_proc(S1,1)
```

gives:

```
467110
C: 70434
467107
C: 70434
```

Which doesnt add up as 3 samples have been removed not 1.

Comment: I must admit that it is very hard to understand your question. It would be easier if you would provide a sample input dataframe and your desired output.

Comment: your sample data does not replicate the change in control labels. Please provide a reproducible sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that when `drop` is used it eliminates based on `index` however my df was a concatenation of serveral dataframes hence I had to use `reset_index` to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only about filtering, why not use:

```
dft = dft[dft['lab'] != 0]
```

This will filter out all rows with `lab=0`.

Comment: Thank you. I only wanted to filter a sample of them not all of them..

Comment: `sample_idx = dft[dft['lab'] == 0].sample(n=100).index; df.drop(sample_idx)`?

Comment: @startswithH well, you had a simple question, but your post is really unreadable...

Comment: @QuangHoang this works as the same as mine, however its also weirdly dropping rows where ```lab == 1```